# Error when using dgesv_: C:\...\Eye Tracker.exe not found

Tags: c++, lapack

I'm trying to solve a simple problem Ax = b using the dgesv_ function. However I've run into a problem I can't get past of. My code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <f2c.h>
#include <clapack.h>

void main(void)
{
    /* 3x3 matrix A
     * 76 25 11
     * 27 89 51
     * 18 60 32
     */
    double A[9] = {76, 27, 18, 25, 89, 60, 11, 51, 32};
    double b[3] = {10, 7, 43};

    int N = 3;
    int nrhs = 1;
    int lda = 3;
    int ipiv[3];
    int ldb = 3;
    int info;

    dgesv_(&N, &nrhs, A, &lda, ipiv, b, &ldb, &info);

}
```

I think the code is correct, however, whenever I run it I get the following error:

```
LINK : C:\...\Eye Tracker.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>     Creating library C:\...\Eye Tracker\Debug\Eye Tracker.lib and object C:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Eye Tracker\Debug\Eye Tracker.exp
1>ellipse_fit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl dgesv_(int const *,int const *,double *,int const *,int *,double *,int const *,int *)" (?dgesv_@@YAXPBH0PAN0PAH102@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ttt(void)" (?ttt@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Eye Tracker\Debug\Eye Tracker.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Are you linking against the lapack libraries? If you are did you compile lapack with visual studio 2010 or use libararies for visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Your error may come from LAPACK not being linked to your program. CLAPACK is easy to link to a C program, but linking to C++ requires adding a few lines. According to http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~cquammen/wp/2010/08/12/calling-clapack-code-from-c/ the following lines should do the trick :

```
extern "C" {
  #include <f2c.h>
  #include <clapack.h>
}
```

If it is not sufficient, here is a working piece of code which can be compiled by `g++ main.cpp -o main -llapack -lblas -lm` :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
extern "C"
{
void dgesv_(int* n,int* nrhs,double* a,int* lda,int* ipiv, double* b,int* ldb,int* info);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* 3x3 matrix A
     * 76 25 11
     * 27 89 51
     * 18 60 32
     */
    double A[9] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0,4};
    double b[3] = {42, 84, 168};

    int N = 3;
    int nrhs = 1;
    int lda = 3;
    int ipiv[3];
    int ldb = 3;
    int info;

    dgesv_(&N, &nrhs, A, &lda, ipiv, b, &ldb, &info);

    cout<<"solution : "<<b[0]<<"  "<<b[1]<<"  "<<b[2]<<endl;
}
```